# Не выводится скрытое поле вместо {% csrf_token %}

Tags: django

Есть вот эдакий шаблон:

```
<div id=shapka style="width:700px; height:100px; border:solid 1px;">
        {% if username %}
            <div>Привет , ({{ username }})
            | <a href='logout'>Выйти</a></div>
        {% else %}
            <form action="login/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label>логин</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <label>пароль</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                {% if login_error %}
                    <label>{{ login_error }}</label>
                {% endif %}
            <input type="submit" value="Войти">
            </form>
        {% endif %}
</div>

результат его вывода вот:
<div id=shapka style="width:700px; height:100px; border:solid 1px;">

            <form action="login/" method="post">

            <label>логин</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <label>пароль</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

            <input type="submit" value="Войти">
            </form>

</div>
```

Отсутствует скрытое поле, которое должно появиться вместо `{% csrf_token %}`.

В файле settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

вот вьюшка

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from django.contrib import auth

from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def main (request):

```
return render_to_response ('main.html', {'username':auth.get_user(request).username})
```

Почему не вывелось скрытое поле?

очков не хватает, чтобы на свой вопрос отвечать. все кто отвечал и задавал вопросы были правы. мне действительно нужно было передать контекст в шаблон. поменял вьюху:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def main (request):
    return render_to_response ('main.html', {'username': auth.get_user(request).username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

теперь все работает. благодарю за участие)

Comment: код view покажи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приучайтесь смотреть исходники.

[Здесь](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py#L53) видно, что пустой HTML будет, если в контексте нет `csrf_token` или он равен "NOTPROVIDED". Причем, если его нет, в консоли будет warning (он есть?).

Ну и смотрите, используется ли [нужный контекст-процессор](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/context_processors.py#L18)